# Custom user and django-registration-redux error when migrate

Tags: django, django-models, django-registration

I just installed `django-registration-redux`, added `'registration'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` and to `urls`, but when migrating, I get next error:

```
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Creating table core_brand
    Creating table core_product
    Creating table core_package
    Creating table core_consignment
    Creating table core_slider
    Creating table core_slideritems
    Creating table order_cart
    Creating table order_order
    Creating table order_orderproduct
    Creating table registration_registrationprofile
    Running deferred SQL...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 179, in handle
    created_models = self.sync_apps(connection, executor.loader.unmigrated_apps)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 317, in sync_apps
    cursor.execute(statement)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "login_customuser" does not exist
```

The problem is that I use `CustomUser` model. I do it in the next way: class

```
CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and in `settings.py` added `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'login.CustomUser'`
Why does this error appear? Because, after this error, I looked into database tables and `login_customuser` exists.

Answer (score 0):

You say you added `login.customuser`. The name is different from `login_customuser` you mentioned elsewhere. Try that to see if it works.
Aside from that, I advise you use `makemigrations` and `migrate` one after the other to have better results.